# Core data: Serious application error

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm finishing my Core Data app ans I started my final testing.

Everyfing works fine, except one thing, that happens **randomly** and I can't reproduce it.

Here is the log (with NSZombieEnabled):

```
2011-07-03 20:27:53.144 MYAPP[1882:707] -[__NSCFType controllerWillChangeContent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4a4c490
2011-07-03 20:27:53.149 MYAPP[1882:707] Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  -[__NSCFType controllerWillChangeContent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4a4c490 with userInfo (null)
2011-07-03 20:27:53.165 MYAPP[1882:707] CoreAnimation: ignoring exception: -[__NSCFType controllerWillChangeContent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4a4c490
```

It crashes here:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; // IT'S OK
NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Kontrahent" inManagedObjectContext:context]; // IT'S OK
for(NSString *key in kontrahent) [newManagedObject setValue:[kontrahent valueForKey:key] forKey:key];  // IT'S OK
NSError *error = nil;
if (![context save:&error]) {  // IT'S NOT OK
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
```

My action hierarchy:

```
1. Open application
2. Open my 'root' list (with NSFetchedResultsController, entity: "Faktura")
3. Tap 'Add' button
4. In my 'Add' view controller I create another object (entity: "Kontrahent")
5. I try to add it to database
6. It crashes / It doesn't.

SCHEME:

        +---[moc save:]---> Faktury (my root class)
        |                        ↓
        +-----delegate-- FakturaCreator <---[moc save:]--+  <--- HERE IT CRASHES
                                 ↓                       |
                         KontrahentCreator ---delegate---+
```

I know that it's connected with `NSFetchedResultsController` and `[moc save:]`. But I can't locate my problem, because it crashes when it wants. Sometimes it works, sometimes it crashes. If you know something abou this problem, please help me :)

---

### IF YOU NEED MORE CODE...

**NSFetchedResultsController stuff `(Faktury.m)`**

```
#pragma mark - Fetched results controller

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    
    if (__fetchedResultsController != nil) return __fetchedResultsController;
    
    // Setup the table
    
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Faktura" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    
    // Setup the sort descriptors
    
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"NumerFV" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    
    // Create the fetched results controller
    
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;
    
    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    [fetchRequest release];
    [sortDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptors release];
    
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Błąd Krytyczny" message:@"Wystąpił nieznany błąd przy zmienianiu zawartości w bazie danych. Dla dobra twoich danych prosimy niezwłocznie wyjść z aplikacji i spróbować ponownie." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
    
    return __fetchedResultsController;
}    

#pragma mark - Fetched results controller delegate

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
            
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    
    if([[[controller sections] objectAtIndex:0] numberOfObjects] == 0) {
        emptySectionView.hidden = NO;
        UIBarButtonItem *editBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edytuj" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(toogleEditing)];
        editBtn.enabled = NO;
        [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:editBtn animated:NO];
        [editBtn release];
    } else {
        emptySectionView.hidden = YES;
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;
    }
    
    UITableView *table = tableView;
    
    switch(type) {
            
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [table insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
            
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [table deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
            break;
            
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:(KSTableViewCell *)[table cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;
            
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [table deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [table insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

**When I tap the add button `(Faktury.m)`**

```
- (void)add:(id)sender {
    FakturaCreator *form = [[FakturaCreator alloc] init];
    form.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    form.delegate = self;
    form.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:form animated:YES];
    [form release];
}
```

Comment: Is this a split view controller app?

Comment: Are you using a table view controller?

Comment: No, it's UITableView inside UIViewController.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I located my problem. I have a 'KontrahentPicker' and it has `NSFetchedResultsController` too. But this `UIViewController` was presented as `modalViewController`. I pucked my `Kontrahent` and modal was dismissed and released. But `NSFRC`'s delegate was still active.

I solved my problem by putting

```
self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = nil;
```

in `-dealloc` method.

Comment: See, told ya! ;) Though this solution is far from perfect. If the KontrahentPicker is modal, holds an NSFetchedResultsController and is its delegate, as soon as it gets dismissed, it should be destroyed completely, along with the NSFRC instance.

Comment: My dealloc sets delegate to nil and then releases NSFRC with NSMOC.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! You just saved me a potential long evening of debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're holding on to a pointer to an object that gets removed from memory before you have the chance to use it. Make sure you're retaining any objects that would otherwise get autoreleased.

From the crash log it would look like the NSFetchedResultsController delegate's pointer points to an already released memory.

Do FakturaCreator and KontrahentCreator exist at the time of saving? Trap the app in their dealloc methods to see if everything is fine there.

Comment: Yes, they exist. `NSFetchedResultsController` is implemented in my root - `Faktury`.

Comment: What is `NSFetchedResultsController`'s delegate and at what point in code do you set it?

Comment: The delegate of NSFRC is `Faktury`.

Comment: Does `Faktury` create the `NSFetchedResultsController`? Do you set Faktury as the delegate at the point of `NSFRC`'s initiation? Is `controllerWillChangeContent:` hit every time? What is its code? There'a a lot of psychic debugging we could do but it would be more productive if you gave us something that would help solve the problem. Need more code! ;)

Comment: So, is `controllerWillChangeContent:` hit every time or is the crash causing it not to be hit occasionally? What's the object that's being sent the `controllerWillChangeContent:` message during the crash?

Comment: @Kashiv let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1131/discussion-between-macbirdie-and-kashiv)

Answer (score 0):

These crashes can also occur if you have a nil value in any of your core data objects.  It would be a good idea to look at each object before saving just to make sure all the properties have values (i.e. nothing says nil or "...not nil...", which indicates an object isn't NSCoding-compliant).  If this is the case, you can simply add a default value for the attributes so they are never nil, then assign them as you go

Comment: All my values are not nil. But if I insert nil `abort()` is called.

Comment: Not nil as in they all have values or do any of them actually say "not nil"?  If it says "not nil", that would be a problem.  Also, it might be a good idea to try and save your managedObjectContext at different areas in the code to see which line is causing the crash.  Try and find where the app functions until you see exactly where the trouble lies.  Considering you say it doesn't happen all the time, I feel this may not help too much, but is certainly worth a try.